# Give an example of a relation R on $A^2$ which is reflexive, symmetric, and not transitive

Tags: discrete-mathematics, self-learning, relations, equivalence-relations

I am just looking for some clarification on this exercise:

Let $A = \{a,b,c,d\}$. Give an example of a relation $R$ on $A^2$ which is reflexive, symmetric, and not transitive.

I understand that if I was only dealing with $A$ and and not $A^2$ I could give an answer similar to:

$R = \{(a,a),(a,b),(a,d),(b,a),(b,b),(c,c),(d,a),(d,d)\}$

Here $R$ is reflexive, symmetric, and not transitive.

What is confusing me is the fact that we have $A^2$. I am not sure what I am missing here. I am looking through my book to see if I can figure this out, but if someone could help shed some light on this it would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Tony

Comment: It doesn't matter what $A$ or $A^2$ looks like. The only binary relation on a set which is both reflexive and not reflexive in the empty relation.

Comment: @GitGud I have edited the body of the question to reflect the title, which I think is what was intended (not transitive)

Comment: I wonder if the "$A$" vs "$A^2$" confusion is really that the underlying set is $A$, but the relation is ordered pairs, so $R\subset A\times A$? This is the usual way, isn't it?

Comment: Mark, that is correct. thanks for catching my typo.

Comment: @Tony You know that $A^2=\{\underbrace{(a,a)}_{x_1}, \underbrace{(a,b)}_{x_2}, \ldots ,\underbrace{ (d,d)}_{x_{16}}\}$. So renaming the elements of $A^2$ reduces the problem to one you know how to solve.

Comment: @MPW I believe that when one says a relation on $X$ one means a subset of $X^2$. This is the most common.

Comment: @GitGud: Yes, that's what I was trying to convey. I just wondered if the OP slightly misstated the problem in that regard. Thanks.

Comment: @GitGud: I see what you are saying. Once I explain what $A^2$ is equal to I believe I could use a directed graph and the answer I provided in my question to show a relation $R$ on $A^2$ that is reflexive, symmetric, and not transitive. Is this correct?

Comment: @Tony I wouldn't mess with graphs, but it works for you, great. It is correct. It would be good if you posted an answer to the question yourself, so this doesn't come up as unanswered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this feed back I believe the answer is:

Let $A = \{a,b,c,d\}$,
$A^2 = A \times A$ = $\{(a,a),(a,b),(a,c),(a,d),(b,a),(b,b),(b,c),(b,d),(c,a),(c,b),(c,c),(c,d),(d,a),(d,b),(d,c),(d,d)\}$

A relation $R$ on $A^2$ which is reflexive, symmetric, and not transitive is:

$R = \{(a,a),(a,b),(a,d),(b,a),(b,b),(c,c),(d,a),(d,d)\}$

R is reflexive because each element is related to itself.

R is symmetric because when one element is related to a second element that second element is related to the first.

R is not transitive because we have $bRa$ and $aRd$ but we do not have $bRd$.